# How to overwrite a package major mode?

Tags: major-mode

I'm a newcomer to Emacs from Vim, I use `rsjx-mode` for react files.  Its major mode calls itself `RJSX`, but I would like to call it `React`, so how can I overwrite the rjsx package major mode name?

Comment: Why and where do you want to "overwrite the...major mode name"? And what do you mean by "overwrite" here? Is this about the value of variable `major-mode`, variable `mode-name`, or something else? (Use `C-h v` to see what those variables are about.)

Comment: Is it the way the mode is named in the mode line that you want to change? If so, please consider rewording the post title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use the `delight` package, you can also just do it by hand:

```
(add-hook 'rsjx-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq mode-name "React")))
```

Comment: Agreed, but noting that `delight` additionally arranges for the original (real) name to still be shown when you do things like `C-h m` (`describe-mode`), with the custom name *only* used in the mode-line.  Conversely a simple `(setq mode-name "React")` would cause `describe-mode` to say something like "React mode defined in rsjx.el", which (IMHO) is potentially confusing. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

If you install the [`delight`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DelightedModes) package:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `package-install` <kbd>RET</kbd> `delight` <kbd>RET</kbd>

You can then add this configuration to your init file:

```el
(delight 'rsjx-mode "React" :major)
```

in order to change the name displayed in the mode line.

Comment: n.b. The change will affect new buffers; any pre-existing buffers in this major mode would need to be reverted for them to show the change.